# VS Code: How to clear linux terminal screen, but keep the previous lines in history

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal, screen, history

In the main Linux terminal, after clearing the screen (`ctrl+l`), the previous lines can still be accessible. However, in VS Code they are removed from the terminal history.

Is there any setting in VS Code to handle this issue?

Output of `Help: About` of VSCode:

```
Version: 1.83.1
Commit: f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc
Date: 2023-10-10T23:45:31.402Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.18.11-200.fc36.x86_64
```

My Linux shell is Bash version 5.1.16.

My Terminal profile: GNOME Terminal - Version 3.44.1 for GNOME 42

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour on Ubuntu 22.04.2 with VS Code 1.84.2 installed as a Snap and a Bash terminal profile in the integrated VS Code terminal with Bash 5.1.16. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Also include what terminal profile you are using, what shell that terminal profile is using, and what version of that shell you have installed.

Comment: related readline docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Moving.html

Comment: you still haven't provided all the info I asked for. still waiting

Comment: I'm asking about which [_VS Code_ terminal profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles) you selected (presumably Bash, but  I want to be certain). I'm also curious to know what happens if you update to VS Code 1.84.2.

Comment: My terminal is Bash. Anyway, it seems by updating to the latest version, the issue has been resolved! I'm not sure if it was a bug-fix or just some modifications in the default VS Code settings.

Comment: This issue still persists. I don't know what happened the previous time that it was resolved temporarily. Anyway, this is not an urgent issue ...